# How to manage multiple subdomains with Amazon EC2?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, dns, webserver, subdomain

I recently registered a domain (say example.com) at GoDaddy.com and I would now like to host many web services in different subdomains using my Amazon EC2 server.

I pointed the domain to my elastic IP address but, is it this enough on the GoDaddy side? That is to say, do I now have to create and manage the subdomains on the Amazon server or at GoDaddy? How should I do it?

Also, what's the advantage between an Amazon route 53 hosted zone and just pointing the domain to the Elastic IP? Is there any advantage?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> do I now have to create and manage the subdomains on the Amazon server
>   or at GoDaddy?

You need to create each subdomain at your DNS service (Godaddy) and point each of those subdomains to your Elastic IP. On the AWS side you will need to configure the web server running on EC2 with the knowledge of each of those subdomains, and what content it needs to serve for each of them.

> what's the advantage between an Amazon route 53 hosted zone and just
>   pointing the domain to the Elastic IP?

There are certain AWS services like Elastic Load Balancers and S3 static websites that do not provide an IP address, only a domain name. To map the root of your domain to one of those services you would have to use Route53 alias records. Route53 also offers features like health checks, failover routing, latency routing, etc. Other than that, there isn't really any advantage to Route53 versus another DNS service like GoDaddy.